# An adornment for the IDE itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

Trying to get started with VS2015 Extensibility. What I have in mind can be classified as an adornment. So I did some research and found sample templates and some MSDN pages that helped me create a basic adornment. Unfortunately though these pages always talk about **text adornments** that work inside the text editors only, whereas my adornment will work across the entire IDE, so at times visuals might appear on top of the Solution Explorer, or the Toolbox etc. There doesn't appear to be a built-in template for that. Can anyone point me in the correction direction about it?